# git rebase merge conflicts for soft links

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

My use case is to insert a new commit after a specific commit in history. I have the hash of the commit after which I need to insert a new commit.

Let's say 
3 is the new commit I want to insert after commit 2 in below history.

```
1 <-- 2 <-- 4 <-- 5 <-- 6
```

I followed the below steps being on master branch.

```
git checkout -b temp <commit 2 hash>
echo "new commit" > test_file.txt
git add test_file.txt
git commit -a -m "Inserting a new commit"
git rebase -Xours temp master
```

I created branch temp from commit 2, made a commit on that branch and did a rebase. Hoping that the history looks like below,

```
1 <-- 2 <-- 3 <-- 4 <-- 5 <-- 6
```

`-Xours` works fine if there any file merge conflicts, but its failing showing merge conflicts in soft links.

The error is something like below

```
Auto-merging apps/abc/ps_abc
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in apps/abc/ps_abc
Auto-merging apps/def/ps_def
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in apps/def/ps_def
```

The above two paths are softlinks to directories outside my git repo. Git diff isn't working for them. How to handle these kind of conflicts??

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

In Git's estimation, a symbolic link named *`P`* (where *`P`* stands for a path like `apps/abc/ps_abc`) is just a file named *`P`* of type "link" whose content is binary.  Since the contents are binary, Git cannot diff them.  You would think `-Xours` would tell Git to use "ours", but it doesn't, because this never drops into the low level code.

The solution is to select the correct version (by whatever means you like) and make sure that it is in the index as the stage-zero version, then continue the operation (in this case `git rebase --continue`).

#### Long

*Merging*—the verb form of *to merge*—is the process of combining changes since a common starting point.  This common starting point is, in Git, the *merge base* commit.  Git finds the merge base using the commit graph: you check out some particular commit with `git checkout mybranch`, then tell Git `git merge theirbranch`.  The two names identify two specific  commits; Git looks at the history behind each of those commits to find the best starting point where the two sets of work diverged.

For each path *`P`* that occurs in all three commits, Git sets up the index / staging-area entry for *`P`* with *all three* files, using the slots within each entry for *`P`* in the index that hold files that are not yet merged.  The base version goes into slot 1.  Our version of that same file goes in slot 2, and their version of that same file goes in slot 3.  A merge conflict then occurs, in general, when *all of the following conditions hold:*

- The version in the base is not the same as the version in the left side.  That is, since the common merge base commit, *we* changed the file with path *`P`*.
- The version in the base is not the same as the version in the right side.  They, too, changed the file with path *`P`*.
- The versions in the left and right sides also differ.  That is, we made a *different* change from the change they made.
- Git is unable to combine these two sets of changes, for some reason.

In the case of *text* (non-binary) files, Git first observes the first three conditions—that the file exists in all three versions, but has changes on both sides—and effectively runs a `git diff` from base to left, and from base to right.  Git can then look at those changes line-group by line-group and *combine* the changes into a single common change.

If this process fails, Git would normally declare a merge conflict and stop.  This would leave, in the index, the *merge base* version of file *`P`* in staging slot 1, the *ours* version in staging slot 2, and the *theirs* version in staging slot 3.  You would then merge these three files however you like—perhaps using the work-tree version that shows the conflict, or maybe using a merge tool that ignores the work-tree version entirely in favor of the original three inputs.  But whatever you do, you generally end this sequence by running `git add P`.  This tells Git to remove the three higher-stage versions and copy whatever is in the work-tree *now*—after you've edited the work-tree version, for instance, or produced a new one using your merge tool—into the index / staging-area as a normal, unconflicted, slot-zero entry for path *`P`*.  This *resolves* the merge conflict.

Using `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs` tells Git that where it would declare such a merge conflict, it should simply override one of the conflicting changes with the other one.  The conflict never shows up!  Normally, the low-level merge process puts the conflict itself into the work-tree file under path *`P`* and leaves the three higher-stage entries in place.  This time, though, this low-level merge process *resolves the conflict automatically* by taking the left/local/`--ours` change (`-Xours`), or by taking the right/remote/`--theirs` change (`-Xtheirs`), ignoring the other side's change to this set of lines.  As long as `git diff` actually matched up the correct set of lines—this is not always the case—the resulting combination of lines probably makes sense.

In any case, with this `X` option, the low level file-merge code handles the conflict for you the way you told it to—by favoring whichever side you told it to favor—and replaces the three higher-stage-number entries for path *`P`* with a normal, stage-zero, all-is-well-with-this-file entry.  So now this particular file is successfully merged and Git goes on to the next set of files in the three commits.

#### This all fails for binary files

With binary files, Git doesn't even attempt to diff the files: they are just changed, or not changed, since the base.  It does not attempt to combine the two diffs using the low-level file merge code.  Since there *is* no low-level file merge, there is nothing to look at your `-X` option and favor one side over the other.

The result is that the merge fails exactly as if you had not used `-X` at all.  The `-X` option is a directive to the *low level merge*—the part of Git that combines two file diffs—and that code never ran at all.  As a result, the merge conflict remains in the index / staging-area, and the merge stops with a merge conflict.  You must resolve this merge conflict yourself.

#### A rebase is a series of cherry-picks and each cherry-pick uses merge-as-a-verb

You might object here and say: *I'm not running `git merge`, I'm running `git rebase`!*  To which the answer is: yes, but `git rebase` is essentially mostly just an automatic repeated series of `git cherry-pick` commands.  One cherry-pick copies one commit, so if rebase needs to copy three commits such as `4--5--6`, rebase runs three cherry-picks on those three commits.  Each `git cherry-pick` is done by using the part of Git that does the *to merge* verb.  The merge base of a cherry-pick is the *parent* of the commit being copied; the left side or `--ours` commit is the commit Git is "standing on" as it does the copy; and the right side or `--theirs` commit is the commit that Git is copying.

Once one cherry-pick finishes, Git then has that commit checked out: that commit is now `--ours` for the next cherry-pick operation.  That is, when you start with:

```
     D--E--F   <-- old-branch
    /
A--B
    \
     C   <-- new-branch
```

and run `git checkout old-branch && git rebase new-branch`, Git will begin by *copying* commit `D` to a new commit `D'` to come after C:

```
     D--E--F   <-- old-branch
    /
A--B
    \
     C   <-- new-branch
      \
       D'  <-- temporary
```

This is a cherry-pick style merge operation; the merge base is `D`'s parent `B` and the `--ours` commit is commit `C`.  Once this merge succeeds and commit `D'` exists, Git goes on to copy commit `E` to `E'`:

```
     D--E--F   <-- old-branch
    /
A--B
    \
     C   <-- new-branch
      \
       D'-E'  <-- temporary
```

which is the second of the three cherry-pick operations.  Now the merge base is `D`, the `--theirs` commit is `E`, and the `--ours` commit is `D'`.  If and when this merge succeeds, Git goes on to copy the last of the three commits, using the third cherry-pick.  Once that succeeds, the commit graph looks like this:

```
     D--E--F   <-- old-branch
    /
A--B
    \
     C   <-- new-branch
      \
       D'-E'-F'  <-- temporary
```

All Git needs to do now is to drop the temporary branch name entirely by *moving* the branch name `old-branch` here:

```
     D--E--F   [abandoned]
    /
A--B
    \
     C   <-- new-branch
      \
       D'-E'-F'  <-- old-branch
```

and the rebase is done.

Because each symbolic link is in effect a binary file, you must merge each such file manually: the low-level merge code that would use `-Xours` never runs.  To choose the `--ours` version—again, this would be the one in `C`, then the one in `D'` then the one in `E'`—you can run `git checkout --ours -- P` to copy the slot-2 version of path *`P`* into the work-tree, then `git add P` to copy the work-tree version of path *`P`* back into the index as stage-zero, resolving the conflict.

(There is a short-cut: you can run `git checkout HEAD -- P` to copy the version from the `HEAD` commit into index slot 0 and into the work-tree.  Since the `--ours` or stage-2 version came *from* `HEAD`, this has the same effect, but uses just one Git command.)